# Can SELinux brick your server?

Tags: centos, selinux

I have enabled SELinux on CentOS Stream (it was in disabled state before, do not know the exact history). I simply changed the following line in `/etc/selinux/config` (it was `disabled` before):

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

Then I reboot and now I am completely out. I cannot login on console, not as user and not as root, not even in recovery mode which I choose during the reboot. Any attempt to login is rejected without any notice.

I made the opposite as user in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873341/cannot-login-to-server-after-disabling-selinux and his trick with ssh on IP is not working, either.

This is a virtual computer. Maybe I made something wrong during editing of that config file, e.g. some typo or accidentally change something (very unlikely but this is so strange). Any idea, what could I try now?

Comment: well, probably not bricked per se.  try rebooting into single user mode, and see if you can't disable it then. https://www.tecmint.com/boot-into-single-user-mode-in-centos-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strict policy will block
everything by default unless you specifically write a policy
to allow it...

Add this to the grub command at boot:
`Kernel...... selinux=0`.